# Italicize title in parenthetical author-title citation (biblatex-mla)

Tags: biblatex, mla-style

When using `biblatex-mla` and there is more than one work per author, the citation style will automatically format parenthetical references as "(Author, Title 123)". However, I'm required to put the "Title" in italics there. How do I do that? Note that in this case, 'multiple books per author' refers to the case of `@bookinbook`, i.e. a one-volume edition of several of the author's books.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=mla, backend=biber]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{%
\mlanamedash%
\iffieldundef{nameaddon}{\adddot\addspace}{\nopunct}}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ford,
author = {Ford Madox Ford},
title = {Parade's End},
publisher = {Vintage Classic},
location = {New York},
date = {2012},
sorttitle = {ford0},
}
@bookinbook{ford:nmp,
crossref = {ford},
title = {No More Parades},
origdate = {1925},
pages = {311--539},
sorttitle = {ford2},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\citeauthor{ford} \autocite[123]{ford:nmp}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Title in parenthetical citation isn't italicized]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The biblatex `mla` cite style provides formatting specifications for the titles depending on the entry type. However, there is no definition for `bookinbook` entry type.  The suitable  definition is

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle:bookinbook}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

With the above definition, the output as expected.

[image]